# check if a number is a positive integer

Tags: sas

Is there a pre-defined function for checking if a number is a positive integer?

**e.g**

`2.17 -> NO`

`3    -> YES`

Currently I'm doing this: `if number - int(number) = 0 then 'YES' else 'NO'`

Comment: You are just checking for number being integer and not for if they are positive or negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct `function` for that, you would have to write logical expressions.

You can use any of the two below, both take same amount of time, one use `mod` function other uses `int`function

```
data _NULL_;
x=236893953323.1235433;
if mod(x,1) = 0 then   /**If you want to check the number is "positive" integer or not then use if mod(x,1) = 0 and x > 0 **/
put "Integer";
else put "Not Integer";
run;
```

OR

```
data _null_ ;
x=236893953323.1235433;
    if x=int(x) then 
put "Integer";
else put "Not Integer";
run ;
```

Comment: NEOmen; your `mod` comment does not work as expected. Removing the decimals from `x` and running it returns "Not Integer". I think you have to use `if mod(x,1) = 0 && x > 0 then`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following improved Bendy's code. It checks for integer and if the sign is positive or negative. I am not aware of a function that checks for both.

```
data _null_ ; 
  do x=-1.4, 1.0, 1.5, -2 ;
    if x=int(x) and sign(x)=1 then put "Positive Integer: " x= ;
    else put "NOT Positive Integer: " x= ;
   end ;
 run ;
```

Result:

```
NOT Positive Integer: x=-1.4
Positive Integer: x=1
NOT Positive Integer: x=1.5
NOT Positive Integer: x=-2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `int()` function to compare:

```
data _null_ ;
  do x=-5,1.4, 1.0, 2 ;
    if x=abs(int(x)) then put "match" x= ;
    else put "not match" x= ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Comment: Bendy, I think the user also wanted to know if the sign is positive or negative. I have improved your answer below a bit by using "sign" function.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice the positive...I've nested it in `abs()`

Comment: That's very neat, works well if a user if looking for positive integer, but you can't use that easily to check for lets say negative integer. :)

Comment: lol - if @W_ee wanted a check for negative integers then can just add an `else if x=int(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an FCMP option to write your own actual function.  You could use any of the other solutions in the function as well.  I like to add the 'fuzz' factor, because these are floating point numbers; so if you want to allow it to be a fuzzy integer (ie, 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 would not add up to a real 1), you add a fuzz factor, otherwise make it zero.  If you don't care about that, get rid of that option.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.func;
    function isInteger(numIn,fuzz);
        isInt = (abs(numIn-int(numIn)) le fuzz) and numIn>0;
        return(isInt);
    endsub;

quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;
data have;
  input x;
  datalines;
-1
-2.17
2.17
3
3.000000000000000000000000001
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  isInt = isInteger(x,0);
  isFuzzy = isInteger(x,1e-12);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like my function:

if (round(number,0) == number then 'Yes' else 'No'

Comment: Because you don't tell us your language so i use the 'human language'

Comment: I think the clue is "sas" tag :)