# SAS how to find negative value in whole dataset?

Tags: sas

I have a large dataset with more than 100 variables. I need to ensure that there are no negative numbers in my dataset. If the dataset contains a negative number, I will need to contact another department. Is there a way to check for negative numbers by using SAS?

thank you!

Comment: Are they all whole numbers?  Can you build a test to see IF the value >= 0 and THEN it passes the test?  The Else segment would be doing what ever code you need to do if it is negative.

Comment: If you can't figure that out, here is a link to a post asking to test for poistive numbers, which I suspect you could invert the logic and get what you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392559/check-if-a-number-is-a-positive-integer

Comment: Do you need to identify the negative values? Or just the presence of any negative values?  Makes a difference it how much output you need to generate and whether you need to keep searching after finding a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are all numeric variables, you could do this with arrays:

```
%let FoundNegative=0 ;

data _null_ ;
  set have ;
  array nums{*} _numeric_ ;
  do i=1 to dim(nums) ;
    if .Z<nums{i}<0 then do ;
      put "Found a negative number! " nums{i}= ;
      call symputx('FoundNegative','1') ;
      stop ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;

%put &=FoundNegative ;
```

Comment: In case there is 0 numeric variable in input dataset(the array statement will report a warning), you can initial a numeric variable with positive value.

Answer (score 1):

Just test if the minimum value is less than zero.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  if min(of _numeric_) < 0;
  put 'Found bad observation at ' _n_= ;
  stop;
run;
```

If it is ok if all of the numbers are missing then you need to exclude those cases.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  if .Z < min(of _numeric_) < 0;
  put 'Found bad observation at ' _n_= ;
  stop;
run;
```